# iphone validation for textfield added in uialertview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have added UITextField in UIAlertView using UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput. I need to validate the textfield present in alertview i.e it should not be empty

How should i do?

Answer (score 11):

Let us assume that you have an "OK" button (or something similar) as the first of the other buttons of the UIAlertView. Further assume that you want that button to be enabled if and only if the length of text in text field is greater than 0. Then the solution to validation is simple. In the delegate of the UIAlertView implement:

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    return [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text length] > 0;
}
```

This has the advantage over some of the other answers (which use clickedButtonAtIndex:), that the user is immediate aware of whether the text field contains valid input.

This delegate message is not terribly well explained in Apple's documentation, but it works very well. Any changes to the value of the text field will cause this message to be sent, and the "OK" button to be enabled or disabled accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can call your validate method from the UIAlertViewDelegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the text field event "Editing Did End", or similar, to a method in the File Owner for handling the validation. The method is one you write in the controller.m file and declare in the controller.h file. The precise name of the controller files depends on the structure of your application code base.

How you handle the case of the validation failing, e.g. content is empty, depends on the needs of your application. For example, if the content is empty, you will need to alert the user then reset focus to the text field.

If you are somewhat new to iOS programming, you may find Ray Wnderlich's tutorials useful. 
  http://www.raywenderlich.com/

I found the "iOS Apprentice" to be nicely done. Also, a new book from Dave Mark, "Beginning iOS 5 Development", may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate of alertView to your current viewController 
then in the delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)return; //for cancel button

    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]; // since there is only one UITextField in alertView
    if ([textField.text length] > 0) // checking the length of the text in UITextField
    {
           // Your code goes here 
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.
BR, Hari

Answer (score 0):

1: Get the `UITextField` in the alertView:

```
self.alertViewTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
```

2: Check the text length when textField editing changed:

```
[self.alertViewTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(alertViewTextFieldDidChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

-(void)alertViewTextFieldDidChanged{
    if(self.alertViewTextField.text.length == 0){
        // ...
    }
}
```